# Pyspark: How to subtract a double from an array(double)

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark, pyspark

I have the following data:

```
import pandas as pd
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession


spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .master('local[*]') \
    .config("spark.driver.memory", "500g") \
    .appName('my-pandasToSparkDF-app') \
    .config("spark.ui.showConsoleProgress", "false")\
    .getOrCreate()
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.execution.arrow.enabled", "true")
spark.conf.set('spark.sql.execution.arrow.maxRecordsPerBatch', 50000)
spark.sparkContext.setLogLevel("OFF")


data = {'array_1': 2.0, 'array_2': [[1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0]}
data = pd.DataFrame(data)
spark_data = spark.createDataFrame(data)

pd_result_frame = spark_data.toPandas()
```

The result looks like this:

```
+-------------------+--------------------+
|array_1            | array_2            |
+-------------------+--------------------+
|2.00000            |[1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0]|
+-------------------+--------------------+
```

In reality I have many rows but for simplicity, my example utilizes only one row.

I would like to add a third column, "abs_diff", which shows the absolute difference between the double in "array_1" and all of the doubles in "array_2", except for the last one. The result should look something like this:

```
+-------------------+--------------------+--------------+
|array_1            | array_2            | abs_diff     |
+-------------------+--------------------+--------------+
|2.00000            |[1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0]|[1.0, 0, 1.0] |
+-------------------+--------------------+--------------+
```

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Higher order functions **`aggregate`** for **`spark>-2.4`** as below-

```scala
 val df = spark.sql("select 2.00000 as array_1, array(1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0) as array_2")
    df.show(false)

    /**
      * +-------+--------------------+
      * |array_1|array_2             |
      * +-------+--------------------+
      * |2.00000|[1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0]|
      * +-------+--------------------+
      */

    df.withColumn("abs_diff",
      expr("TRANSFORM(slice(array_2, 1, size(array_2)-1), x -> abs(x-array_1))"))
      .show(false)

    /**
      * +-------+--------------------+---------------------------+
      * |array_1|array_2             |abs_diff                   |
      * +-------+--------------------+---------------------------+
      * |2.00000|[1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0]|[1.00000, 0.00000, 1.00000]|
      * +-------+--------------------+---------------------------+
      */
```

Comment: From documentation for `array_remove`: `Collection function: Remove all elements that equal to element from the given array.` This means that you would remove everything equal to 2, not just the last element.

Comment: One additional question: How is it possible to delete all values from abs_diff which are, let's say, bigger than 0.5?

Comment: use filter - https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#filter

Comment: Thank you, this is absolutely working. I expressed myself misleadingly. It's about introducing a variables into the string: If have:

withColumn("abs_diff_filter", F.expr("filter(abs_diff, x -> x >= 1)")). This works. But I need:

withColumn("abs_diff_filter", F.expr("filter(abs_diff, x -> x >= z)")) and z is an auxiliary variable.

Comment: ok, no it is clear: 

 withColumn("abs_diff_filter", F.expr(f"filter(abs_diff, x -> x >= {z})"))